# Modifying Pydantic json_encoders for a class not working

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic model that has an instance of another model as one of its attributes.

For my application, I need that model to be written out in a custom way. I thought I could do this by setting *json_encoders* in the model Config but I can't get it working. I can get it to work for basic types eg. datetime but not with my own class.

See minimal example below:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


def write_list_item(item):
    return [item.a, item.b]


class ListItem(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str


class ToyList(BaseModel):
    list_item: ListItem

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {ListItem: write_list_item}


tl = ToyList(list_item=ListItem(a="a1", b="b2"))

print(tl.json())
```

Expected output:

```
["a1, "b1"]
```

Observed output:

```
{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}
```

Can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it is not straightforwardly possible. It will be possible when [this PR](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/2650) is merged.

Therefore, you can consider a different design of the model or a workaround through a custom root type, for example (not production-ready):

```py
class ListItem(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[str]

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def root_val(cls, values):
        return {"__root__": [values['a'], values['b']]}

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.__root__[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.__root__[1]

    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        if key == 'a':
            self.__root__[0] = val
        elif key == 'b':
            self.__root__[1] = val
        else:
            super().__setattr__(key, val)
```

Comment: great answer thanks. will keep an eye on the PR :)